# How to Write If!=IsNull in Sql StoredProceddure

Tags: stored-procedures

Here i Wrote a Small StoredProcedure when Id is not available It shows Else
Please Helpme

```
Alter procedure Sp_GetEmpById
(@Id int)
As
Begin
if(@Id!==ISNULL){
select Email,Gen,Country from Employee where Emp_Id =@Id
}
Else
print 'The Id Enter By u is Not  Availabe '+@Id
End
```

Here i get Two Error at ISNULL And `Then Id Enter By u is Not in Availabe '+@Id
@Id`

Comment: What if @id is not null, but this id does not exist in the `Employee` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will compile, however I am not sure about your requirements:

```
create procedure Sp_GetEmpById @Id int
as
begin
if @Id is not NULL
    select Email,Gen,Country from Employee where Emp_Id = @Id
else
    print 'The Id Enter By u is Not  Availabe ' + @Id

end
```